# How to properly configure pytest with FastAPI and Tortoise ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am trying to configure the tests. According to the tortoise orm documentation I create this test configuration file:

```
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from tortoise.contrib.test import finalizer, initializer

import app.main as main
from app.core.config import settings

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def initialize_tests(request):
    db_url = "postgres://USERNAME_HERE:SECRET_PASS_HERE@127.0.0.1:5432/test"
    initializer(
        [
            "app.models",
        ],
        db_url=db_url,
        app_label="models"
    )
    print("initialize_tests")
    request.add_finaliser(finalizer)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client():
    app = main.create_application()
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        print("client")
        yield client
```

And the test file looks like this:

```
def test_get(client):
    response = client.get("/v1/url/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I try to run the tests, but I get this error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

I have found that some users don't use initializer and finalizer and do everything manually.
[Testing in FastAPI using Tortoise-ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716897/testing-in-fastapi-using-tortoise-orm)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907531
But that doesn't look like the clear solution.
Question: Is there a way to make the tests work using initializer and finalizer?